# Проблема с назначением в инспекторе

Tags: c#, unity3d

Суть проблемы в следующем: Есть статический родитель(префаб) и есть дети, которые динамически появляются на уровне кода, беря за основу родителя. Так же в них есть InputField и клавиатура, которая появляется при нажатии на InputField. Сама клавиатура привязана в инспекторе к скрипту, который висит на InputField. В самом префабе клавиатура появляется без проблем, но когда появляются дети, то у них клавиатура слетает в инспекторе со скрипта и, соответственно, она не работает. Как это можно решить??

Comment: Слово "суть" есть, а самой сути нету :/

Comment: @RiotBr3aker что вам непонятно? Напишите, пожалуйста. Расскажу поподробнее

Comment: Из вашего рассказа ничего не понять, "динамически появляются на уровне **кода**", где код? Что значит "беря за основу родителя"? Что за клавиатура и как она привязана к какому-то скрипту? Что и где слетает тоже не ясно.